# Getting an error but even when unwrapped I have no output of image , using Kingfisher for the first time

Tags: swift, uitableview

I am using Kingfisher for the first time and I can not seem to get my app running where it takes an Image from firebase and views it in the prototype cell which will have 'ViewImage'

I have tried unwrapping but it does not work as I get more errors therefore I have looked online and most people have coded this line the same as me but are experiencing no errors.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ImageCell") as! ImageCell    
    let resource = ImageResource(downloadURL: URL(string: arrayOfImages[indexPath.row])!, cacheKey: arrayOfImages[indexPath.row])    
    cell.imgView.kf.setImage(with: resource)    
    return cell
}
```

The error I am getting is with `let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ImageCell") as! ImageCell`

```
Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
```

Comment: That is not a problem with kingfisher. Did you register your cell with your tableView?

Comment: yes but the problem is still with 'let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ImageCell") as! ImageCell'

Comment: Can you show us how you register it?

Comment: self.tableview.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "ImageCell")

Comment: Aha! There it is. If you register the cell as a normal cell and try to dequeue an `ImageCell` it will obviously crash! Register the cell as an `ImageCell`.

Comment: I will have a look at that but what about the error of: Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Comment: That is causing the error! It is trying to dequeue a cell of type `ImageCell` but your cell is `UITableViewCell`!

Comment: I got that working now the error is in cell.imgView.kf.setImage(with: resource) it says Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value